# Is there a way to make a section of the paint() method only run once in Java?

Tags: java, graphics, paint, repaint

I am trying to make an Uno game (not important), so I need to draw some rectangles and images at the start of the game to set up. However, when the deck is clicked, it needs to add a card to the player's hand. This would obviously be at a different time than the original setup, but since it involves drawing a card, doesn't it also need to be within paint()? I tried to fix this by creating booleans and changing them depending on if the drawing has already been made, but when I did that it now does not draw the start drawing at all. Is there an easier way to do this or at least a solution to this issue? There is a lot more code, but I think what I have below is all that is needed for this issue. Thanks!

public class ImageCreator {

```
private boolean hasStartedDrawing = false;
private boolean drawCardPlayer = false;

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
{  
    if ((e.getX() >= 472 && e.getX() <= 662) && (e.getY() >= 205 && e.getY() <= 455))
    {
        drawCardPlayer = true;
        repaint();
    }
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    if (hasStartedDrawing == false)
    {
        Rectangle rect0P = new Rectangle(50, 650, 95, 125); g2.draw(rect0P); 
        hasStartedDrawing = true;
    {
    if (drawCardPlayer)
    {
        game.drawCardPlayer(g); //a method in another class that actually draws the card
        drawCardPlayer = false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If you're using Swing, you should be overriding paintComponent() rather than paint().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it just great! Just a little detail, I struggle with it too in the beggining.

The best aproach is to override ***paintComponent***, and then call ***repaint*** every time what you need to update or "draw" the GUI again.
If you need a more deep explanation, here you have the "why": https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html

And if you need some easy (but important) examples, here you have (also from Oracle Documentation): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html

Comment: Thank you! After struggling all day, I finally figured everything out, definitely a beginner's mistake (first time coding graphics). I was doing too much in paint(), it should only be used for drawing!